# How to uniquely identify a socket id in tcp socket listener

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a socket server written in node js. I have GPS trackers which are sending data continuously after 5 seconds to my TCP server. I want to uniquely identify each socket so that I query the database only when the new connection establishes not every 5 seconds. For example, this is what I wanted to do.

1. Data comes from the device to my socket server
2. I will save the device id and socket id in an array and query the database and fetch some results and save it in the same array
3. When GPS tracker sends data again, I will check if the socket id exists, if it does then I will use that saved data instead of querying the database again. and if socket doesn't exist, I will query again the database and save it.

But the issue is that I couldn't get a socket id by doing this `socket.id`

This is what I have tried so far but it's not working for me. I have given unique ids to the socket but its keep on generating the new unique ids for the same socket connection. Please help

```
const Net = require('net');



  socketarray =  [
   { "socket_id": 0, "socket": 0,"string":"0" }
   
];
 

const server = new Net.Server();

 const HOST = "ip";
const PORT =  8888;

 server.listen(PORT, HOST);

var new_no = 0;
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A new connection has been established.');

 

    

   
    socket.on('data', function(chunk) {

    socketarray.map(function (element,index) {
      //console.log(element);
  if (element.socket == socket) {
    console.log("socket id is" + element.socket_id +  "index is " + index + "string is" + element.string);
     console.log("index is" + index);
   
  } else {

    socketarray.push( { "socket_id":  Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), "socket": socket,"string":chunk.toString() });
    console.log("new entry");
 
  }
});

    });



  
    socket.on('end', function() {

       
        console.log('Closing connection with the client');






    });

   
    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Create id yourself (uuid or something) and keep track of it as {id: socket} dict, instead of sockets.push(socket), which suggest a list. Then you can also easily remove such socket from the dict on close.

Comment: So, `socket.id` is not a feature of a TCP socket.  Perhaps you're confusing it with socket.io connections which do create a `socket.id` property.  In any case, if you need a unique id, you can just create your own id and assign it as that property upon connection.  Or, you can just use the socket object itself as the ID depending upon what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Note, your general description of avoiding database repeat lookups sounds like a general purpose DB query cache could be used also.

Comment: @freakish Please check I have updated my question

Comment: @jfriend00 Please check I have updated my question

Comment: Perhaps you can show why you're even trying to create this `socketarray`.  Please show the REAL problem.  Right now, you have only asked about side effects or problems with your attempted solution to some problem, but you have never explained what the real problem is.  This code looks like it's going to run on ever `data` event from every socket and it's going to add a whole bunch of stuff to `socketarray` for every socket that isn't the one sending the data and it's going to do that over and over again.  No point in trying to fix this until we know what the REAL problem is here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay the real issue is that I don't want to query database every 5 second for each device. I am already doing that and it increases the ram and my server freezes after 3 days and I have only 500 devices connected. So in order to limit the db queries I want to query just once for one device and save that data in an array. This is what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is to "store" some data from a query in a place you can associate with a given connection so you can use it on future activities on that connection, then you can just store it as a property of that socket object:

```
socket.on('data', async data => {
    let socketInfo = socket.info;
    if (!socketInfo) {
        try {
            // do your db query to get the data for this socket
            socketInfo = socket.info = await getDataForSocket(socket, data);
        } catch(e) {
            // do something here if db query error
        }
    }
    // now you have socketInfo for this socket
    // and you only ever queried for it once during the
    // lifetime of this socket
});
```

No socketarray is needed.  No unique id is needed for this type of solution.

Comment: @mynameisbutt - Where's you go?  If all you want to do is save some socket-specific data, you can just attach it to a property like this shows.  Will this work for you?

Comment: I am sorry I got sick. Are you available? can we discuss this over chat?

Comment: @mynameisbutt - If you have a question about my answer, you should ask it in the comments here.